# Lounge in Doha?

Tags: lounges, doha, doh

We are travelling to Bangkok through Doha with Qatar Airways (economy). Is there a priority pass lounge there? We are from Denmark and have a private banking priority pass and a platinum Mastercard.

Comment: With which airline? What fare?

Comment: Qatar Airways - economy

Comment: Thanks! I don't know if that's relevant but it's best to provide as much info as possible so I added that to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Per the official Priority Pass site, **[no](http://www.prioritypass.com/mobile/index.cfm?plan=290362&sourcecode=GOOPCTAB10)**, there isn't.

Not aware of any lounges that your Mastercard would let you into either, these tend to be regional anyway (= card must be issued in the Middle East to qualify).